# PHP: Why does DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() function list UTC instead of GMT

Tags: php, timezone

Why does PHP's DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() function list **UTC** instead of **GMT**.?

GMT is a timezone where as UTC is a standard as per http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it lists both, as well as several other names for the same thing:

```
GMT            GMT+0          GMT-0        GMT0        UTC        UCT
Etc/GMT        Etc/GMT+0      Etc/GMT-0    Etc/GMT0    Etc/UTC    Etc/UCT

Greenwich      Universal      Zulu
Etc/Greenwich  Etc/Universal  Etc/Zulu
```

You can review [PHP's list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php), or [the generic tzdb list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

The canonical form in the [TZDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (where these originate) is `"Etc/UTC"`, but the definition of *canonical* could be different for each consumer.  For example, the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org) considers `"Etc/GMT"` to be canonical by its rules.  Other systems may regularly use `"UTC"` or `"GMT"`.  Those four are the main ones, the rest are mostly there for backwards compatibility reasons and should be usually avoided.

As to *why* these terms are used interchangeably, it's because for all intent and purpose they are identical in our modern usage of them.  See [UTC vs GMT on my blog](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/06/18/utc-vs-gmt/).

In general, this is my educated opinion:

- Use `GMT` when referring specifically to the portion of the UK time zone that is not in daylight saving time (use `BST` during daylight time), or as used year-round in places like Iceland and others (unless they have a different convention used locally).
- Use `GMT` in *British* contexts, such as how the [BBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC) announces time in GMT.
- Prefer `UTC` in time zone offsets, especially when fully qualified, such as `UTC-08:00` or `UTC+05:30`.  It is *acceptable* to use `GMT` in the short form with whole-hour offsets such as `GMT+2` or `GMT-5`, but they should still be avoided (IMHO) do to their lack of precision.  Additionally, most legal documents defining time zones of various countries refer to Coordinated Universal Time, which is UTC - not GMT.
- In all other cases, and when uncertain, prefer `UTC`.

[The timeanddate.com article](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html) you refer to is not wrong - it's just a matter of interpretation and perspective.  From a *terminology* perspective, it's absolutely correct that GMT is a time zone, and UTC is a system of timekeeping.

I'll give you a short history lesson:

- GMT was invented first, and was *originally* defined as the mean solar time observed by the observatory in Greenwich, England.  That literally meant looking through telescopes to check the position of stars, doing some math to figure out the rotation speed and position of the Earth, and setting a clock by hand with the results.  This eventually became more automated, resulting in the [UT1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time) standard,
- UTC came later, and was defined with much more scientific precision.  UTC is based on the [TAI atomic clock standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time), plus the [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) that are inserted periodically to keep it aligned to within 0.9 seconds of UT1.
- As UTC was adopted, GMT eventually came to mean UTC in civil contexts.  Today, when you hear the term GMT, it is *identical* in value to UTC.  GMT itself is no longer precisely defined.
- It's also worth mentioning that GMT originally considered a "day" to start at noon, rather than midnight.  We rarely do that anymore, including when we use the term "GMT".

[Wikipedia's article on GMT has a lot more of the history if you are interested.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)